MAUI show DateTime.Now - CultureInfo("fa-IR")
How can I display today's date in the label in different languages?
I use the following code, but the date is displayed with en-US .
lbltime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd" , new CultureInfo("fa-IR"));



what exactly is is displaying, and what do you expect it to display?

Your Windows (or other OS, if you're using Xamarin) seems to not have the language/culture files for fa-IR, so .NET's localization system simply falls-back to fa

which is any Farsi-language culture definition on your computer, if available; but if not then it defaults to InvariantCulture as a last-resort. As Microsoft is a US company I don't blame them for basing InvariantCulture on en-US - I'm just annoyed that it's hardcoded to always use the lopsided MM/dd/yyyy instead of, say, RFC 3339 / ISO 8601.


Did you mean you want to show the label's text as fa-IR? In addition, you can refer to the case about How to implement .NET MAUI localization.
